# Java - Regex to split mathematical expression for operator excluding operator which comes under brackets

Tags: java, regex

I need to split below string using below regex. but it splits data which comes under brackets.

```
Input
T(i-1).XX_1 + XY_8 + T(i-1).YY_2 * ZY_14

Expected Output
T(i-1).XX_1 , XY_8 , T(i-1).YY_2 , ZY_14
```

It should not split data which comes under "(" and ")";

I tried with below code but split data which comes under  "(" and ")"

```
String[] result = expr.split("[+*/]");
```

any pointer to fix this.

I am new to this regex.

```
Input
(T(i-1).XX_1 + XY_8) + T(i-1).YY_2 * (ZY_14 + ZY_14)
Output
T(i-1).XX_1 , XY_8 , T(i-1).YY_2 , ZY_14 , ZY_14
```

if it is T(i-1) need to ignore.

For below expression its not working

```
XY_98 + XY_99 +XY_100
String lineExprVal = lineExpr.replaceAll("\\s+","");
String[] result = lineExprVal.split("[+*/-] (?!(^))");
```

Comment: Is there always going to be just 1 level of parentheses?

Comment: @markusthoemmes. yes. only one level of parentheses

Comment: Can your input outside parentheses contain a `-` sign? As it is, even your simple regex works.

Comment: @Raje i already post a new answer like i promise hope this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Split** in your second mathematical expression is really hard if it is not possible, so instead you have to use **pattern**, it is more helpful, so for your expression, you need this regex :

```
(\w+\([\w-*+\/]+\).\w+)|((?:(\w+\(.*?\))))|(\w+)
```

Here is a [Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/KrGxaM/1/) you will understand more.

To get the result you need to loop throw your result :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "(T(i-1).XX_1 + XY_8) + X + T(i-1).YY_2 * (ZY_14 + ZY_14) + T(i-1)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\([\\w-*+\\/]+\\).\\w+)|((?:(\\w+\\(.*?\\))))|(\\w+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    List<String> reslt = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {//loop throw your matcher 
        if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
            reslt.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
//In your case you have to avoid this two groups 
//            if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
//                reslt.add(matcher.group(2));
//            }
//            if (matcher.group(3) != null) {
//                reslt.add(matcher.group(3));
//            }
        if (matcher.group(4) != null) {
            reslt.add(matcher.group(4));
        }
    }
    reslt.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This will gives you :

```
T(i-1).XX_1
XY_8
X
T(i-1).YY_2
ZY_14
ZY_14
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split every thing outside your parentheses like this :

```
String str = "T(i-1).XX_1 + XY_8 + T(i-1).YY_2 * ZY_14";
String result[] = str.split("[+*/-] (?!(^))");
//---------------------------^----^^--List of your delimiters

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

This will print :

```
[T(i-1).XX_1 , XY_8 , T(i-1).YY_2 , ZY_14]
```

The idea is simple you have to split with your delimiters that not inside your parenthesis.

You can check this here [ideone](https://ideone.com/Si3fod) and you can check your regex here [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSXnQ2/2/)

---

**EDIT**

In your second case you have to use this regex :

```
String str = "(T(i - 1).XX_1 + XY_8)+  (i - 1).YY_2*(ZY_14 + ZY_14)";
String result[] = str.split("[+*+\\/-](?![^()]*(?:\\([^()]*\\))?\\))");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

This will give you :

```
[(T(i-1).XX_1+XY_8), T(i-1).YY_2, (ZY_14+ZY_14)]
 ^----Group1------^  ^--Groupe2-^  ^--Groupe3-^
```

You can find the [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQzDNl/1), i inspirit this solution from this post here [Regex to match only comma's but not inside multiple parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195975/regex-to-match-only-commas-but-not-inside-multiple-parentheses) .

Hope this can help you.

Comment: could you explain the regex. I can't understand the second part of it.

Comment: But even this `[+*/]` regex will print the same output. What's the point, I don't get it. If you have `-` signs outside parentheses, this regex won't work.

Comment: YCF_L  for Subtraction it gives some different result T(i-1).XX_1 - XY_8 + T(i-1).YY_2 * ZY_14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138928/discussion-between-ycf-l-and-raje).