# Match commas, excluding those in parentheses - RE2 for Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

Okay, hear me out! I've seen dozens of similar RegEx questions, but context is everything! I'm trying to incorporate a regular expression search into a Google Sheets function that will match all commas from a long string, while excluding commas inside parentheses. Should be simple enough, however, Google Sheets uses RE2 which apparently isn't fond of lookarounds and frequently throws a depressing error ("parameter 2 value "whatever" is not a valid regular expression."). So, many of the approaches I've taken have been unsuccessful.

I should note that I MUST use Google Sheets for this process (per my boss), I'm pulling the data directly into Sheets from one of our APIs and its structure within the API cannot change. Any other advice is totally welcome!

Here's what the data looks like:

> Almonds_111, Amaranth_222, Anchovy_333, Apple (medium, organic)_444, Apricot_5555, Artichoke_6666

I need to match the primary commas so I can either delimit by them (or change them and delimit by a new character), while keeping the data around the secondary comma intact (i.e. "(medium, organic)").

Here's some of what I've tried so far:

- Tidy lookaround that works in regex101, but not in Sheets

  ```
  (?<=\d),
  ```
- More complex lookaround that doesn’t work in Sheets (or regex101 heh)

  ```
  ,(?=(((?!\]).)*\()|[^\[\)]*$)
  ```
- An attempt at non-capturing group (also, I must be missing something about the non-capturing vs. capturing group concept?? Because the non-cap group is still included when I run this...)

  ```
  (?:\d)(,)
  ```
- Matches correctly in regex101 but not Sheets

  ```
  ,\s*(?![^()]*\))
  ```

Alright, that's the gist! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the one on this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195975/regex-to-match-only-commas-but-not-inside-multiple-parentheses

Comment: What function are you using? If you need to match those strings, use `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?:\([^()]*\)|[^,])+")`

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Thanks! Unfortunately, that expression doesn't work in Sheets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using REGEXREPLACE, but I'm not married to it. I made attempts at changing my delimiter to a pipe instead of commas. I'm trying to incorporate your expression now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same error! Sheets is so finicky. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error? What are you trying to get? You have `Almonds_111, Amaranth_222, Anchovy_333, Apple (medium, organic)_444, Apricot_5555, Artichoke_6666` in a cell? Now, what is the end result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Apologies, it works, but cuts off everything after the first row! I'm nesting an ArrayFormula that imports my JSON data, splits it by commas (or some other character), transposes it into a column, then splits again by the "_".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my next attempt is to just replace the internal commas with something innocuous and move on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might suit:

```
=regexreplace(substitute(A1,",","#"),regexextract(substitute(A1,",","#"),"\(.+\)"),regexextract(A1,"\((.+)\)"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input @pnuts! Gonna give this a shot.

Comment: Ahh almost! Output = "Barley_111#Cane Sugar_222#Cassava_333#Corn Tortilla (organic# non-GMO)_444#Couscous_555#"

Comment: Unfortunately, the internal commas are still being replaced on my end. But I'm sure this is due to the fact that the data from my first argument (A1) is actually coming from a function that imports JSON into Sheets. Looks great though! Thanks.